# RedirectToAction em JavaScript não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, controller, requisição

Após uma validação eu chamo o controller (Perfil) na action (Adiciona) para adicionar um novo registro através de javascript.

Se der certo a inserção eu dou `RedirectToAction` para o index deste mesmo controller passando o id do perfil que acabei de cadastrar, porém **nada** acontece!

JavaScript:

```
function validaFormulario() {
    var formularioValidado = false;

    formularioValidado = validaFormulario();

    if (formularioValidado) {
        var perfil = obtemPerfilDoFormulario();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Perfil/Adiciona',
            data: {
                "perfil": perfil
            },
            async: false,
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Adiciona(Perfil perfil)
{
    PerfilDAO perfilDAO = new PerfilDAO();
    perfil.UsuarioId = usuario.Id;
    perfilDAO.Adiciona(perfil);

    EnviaEmailRecebimentoCadastro(perfil.Email);

    EnviaEmailAtivacaoDeConta(perfil.Email);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Perfil", perfil.Id);
}
```

Consegui contornar o problema enviando o id do perfil por Json e fazendo manualmente o redirecionamento pelo javascript adicionamento o retorno "success".

Esta abordagem estaria correta? Estou iniciando em desenvolvimento web e queria uma orientação sobre essas "boas práticas". Afinal, o `RedirectToAction` do meu controller deveria funcionar. Onde cometi o erro?

Código com o problema contornado:

Controller enviando Json:

```
public ActionResult Adiciona(Perfil perfil)
{
    //restante do codigo

    return Json(perfil.Id);
}
```

Javascript com success:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Perfil/Adiciona',
        data: {
            "perfil": perfil
        },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var id = JSON.parse(data);
                window.location.href = "/Usuario/Lista/" + id;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
```

Comment: Você está adicionando a anotação [HttpPost] em cima da Action adiciona?

Comment: Acredito que seja isso mesmo, HttpPost pois o window.location.href = "/Usuario/Lista/" + id; é um GET, quando você não adiciona a anotação [HttpPost] em cima da sua Action automaticamente por padrão ela é um [HttpGet]. Tenta adicionar isso em cima da sua Action [HttpPost] e vê se trouxe resultado.

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa pergunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767911/mvc-httppost-httpget-for-action

Comment: @leonardo, na verdade o 'window.location.href = Usuario/Lista/" + id' functiona! O meu problema é no controller, onde ele não redireciona para a view Index do controller Perfil. O httpPost neste caso é explicito na chamada assíncrona $.ajax com o type: 'POST'.

Comment: Mas ele chega a passar no ActionResult Adiciona ? porque esse método ao meu ver é um GET, se você instrui o server-side a executar um Post ele vai procurar o Post, posso estar errado... mas ja aconteceu comigo, ele chega a executar a action?

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti ele executa sim... Estou debugando e ele passa pela action Adiciona sim. O problema é que quando ele cai na linha  'return RedirectToAction("Index", "Perfil", perfil.Id);' ele não absolutamente nada...

Comment: Ahhhh, agora eu entendi.

Comment: @LucasFerriani E nem deve fazer. **Este é o comportamento esperado**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua primeira premissa está bem errada.

Ao fazer uma requisição assíncrona para o *server-side*, você deveria retornar dados ou qualquer coisa que fosse possível de tratar pelo lado cliente usando JavaScript, fazer um redirecionamento não causará efeito nenhum.

A segunda ideia é a melhor forma de fazer o que você pretende. Nela é feita a requisição Ajax para o servidor, o mesmo retorna o dado para que o cliente (JavaScript) se encarregue do redirecionamento.

Comment: essa era a resposta que eu queria ter. No caso, existe algum jeito de eu somente chamar o controller sem esperar nenhum retorno e deixar que ele se encarregue de fazer o redirecionamento? Do mesmo modo que ele funciona quando tenho no html um form com o atributo action="/Controler/Action" e clico no botão submit?

Comment: Não, jovem. Porque o JS não vai fazer nada um código de redirecionamento.

Comment: muito obrigado man! :)